# backbone.validation integration with brunch.io( backbone.js framework)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, brunch

How to intergrate http://thedersen.github.com/backbone.validation/ with brunch.io i tried putting backbone.validation.js in vendor folder and

```
View = require './view'
template = require './templates/home'
User = require 'models/user'

module.exports = class HomeView extends View
 id: 'home-view'
 template: template

initialize: ->

 Backbone.Validation.bind(this)

 @user = new User

 console.log @user

 @user.validate()
```

Gives error Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'validate'

then i also tried

```
# The application bootstrapper.
Application =
 initialize: ->
HomeView = require 'views/home_view'
Router = require 'lib/router'
User  = require 'models/user'
# Ideally, initialized classes should be kept in controllers & mediator.
# If you're making big webapp, here's more sophisticated skeleton
# https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin
@homeView = new HomeView model: new User

# Instantiate the router
@router = new Router()
# Freeze the object
Object.freeze? this

module.exports = Application
```

and this also

```
Model = require './model'
HomeView = require 'views/home_view'


 module.exports = class User extends Model

 defaults:
    logged_in: false,
    token: false

 initialize: ->
   new HomeView model: new User

 validation: 
     email: {
       required: true,
       pattern: 'email',
       msg: 'Please enter a valid email' },
     name:  {
       required: true,
       msg: "Name is required" }
```

Gives error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

So none of the tricks worked for i need helpt o solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should have put in backbone.validation.js in the vendor/scripts folder.
Did you see that you have to unclude Backbone and Underscore before the plugin?

Brunch works with configuration files and you should have in your config.coffee something like:

```
exports.config =
  # See docs at http://brunch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html.

  # Edit the next line to change default build path.
  paths:
    public: 'public'

  files:
    javascripts:
      # Defines what file will be generated with `brunch generate`.
      defaultExtension: 'coffee'
      # Describes how files will be compiled & joined together.
      # Available formats:
      # * 'outputFilePath'
      # * map of ('outputFilePath': /regExp that matches input path/)
      # * map of ('outputFilePath': function that takes input path)
      joinTo:
        'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
        'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
      # Defines compilation order.
      # `vendor` files will be compiled before other ones
      # even if they are not present here.
      order:
        before: [
          'vendor/scripts/console-helper.js',
          'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js',
          'vendor/scripts/underscore-1.3.3.js',
          'vendor/scripts/backbone-0.9.2.js'
          'vendor/scripts/backbone.validation.js'
        ]
```

What it's important is the order section.

Answer (score 0):

1) You bind the validation thingie to the view, not user so thats why you get the first error

2) You shouldnt create views inside of a model,